# iOS game coins for FB like/Twitter follow/Youtube subscription

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, cocos2d-iphone, youtube

We are creating a game and would like to make our players like/subscribe/follow our FB/YT/Twitter pages for which we would give them rewards (in-game coins).

Most games, that i checked, give users the reward as soon as they click the "like" button (even if they later don't actually like the page that is shown).

so i was wondering if it's possible to detect actual likes/subscriptions/follows and only reward users after the confirmation is received?

Is it worth the added trouble at all?

Any info is appreciated!

BR,
Rok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use completion handlers.

Facebook SDK:

```
+ (FBRequestConnection*)startWithGraphPath:(NSString*)graphPath
                                parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
                                HTTPMethod:(NSString*)HTTPMethod
                         completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

and `FBRequestHandler` is

```
typedef void (^FBRequestHandler)(FBRequestConnection *connection, 
                                 id result,
                                 NSError *error);
```

If error isn't nil, then request obviously did not succeed. You can also check that `result` has expected values.

iOS6's Social framework (handler block parameters are NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error):

```
- (void)performRequestWithHandler:(SLRequestHandler)handler;
```

iOS5's Twitter framework:

```
- (void)performRequestWithHandler:(TWRequestHandler)handler;
```

In Twitter's case you should check status code of the returned NSHTTPURLResponse (200 means "success").

Comment: just figured the twitter part out a while back.

Tnx!